# Webscraper using BeautifulSoup on Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an assignment to make a web scraper using BeautifulSoup.
There are certain functions defined in the code.
How do I pass the bs4.element.ResultSet to another function and extract relevant data in the form of a dictionary as bs4.element.ResultSet is passed as a python list file.

Here is the code I have been able to write so far, comments are included for further information.

```
def fetchWebsiteData(url_website):
"""Fetches rows of tabular data from given URL of a website with data excluding table headers.

Parameters
----------
url_website : str
    URL of a website

Returns
-------
bs4.element.ResultSet
        """

web_page_data = ''
####
req = requests.get(url_website)
soup= BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
web_page_data = soup.find_all('tbody')
####    
return web_page_data
```

The other function that I am using:

```
def fetchVaccineDoses(web_page_data):
"""Fetch the Vaccine Doses available from the Web-page data and provide Options to select the respective Dose.

Parameters
----------
web_page_data : bs4.element.ResultSet
    All rows of Tabular data fetched from a website excluding the table headers

Returns
-------
dict
    Dictionary with the Doses available and Options to select, with Key as 'Option' and Value as 'Command'

Example
-------
>>> url_website = "https://www.mooc.e-yantra.org/task-spec/fetch-mock-covidpage"
>>> web_page_data = fetchWebsiteData(url_website)
>>> print(fetchVaccineDoses(web_page_data))
{'1': 'Dose 1', '2': 'Dose 2'}
"""

vaccine_doses_dict = {}
####


for dose in web_page_data:
    dose = dose.find_all('td', class_="dose_num")
    
    for k in dose:
        #print (k.next_element)
        if (k.next_element) == 1:
            vaccine_doses_dict['1'] = "Dose 1"
        else:
            vaccine_doses_dict['2'] = "Dose 2"
####
return vaccine_doses_dict
```

And:

```
def fetchAgeGroup(web_page_data, dose):
"""Fetch the Age Groups for whom Vaccination is available from the Web-page data for a given Dose
and provide Options to select the respective Age Group.

Parameters
----------
web_page_data : bs4.element.ResultSet
    All rows of Tabular data fetched from a website excluding the table headers
dose : str
    Dose available for Vaccination and its availability for the Age Groups

Returns
-------
dict
    Dictionary with the Age Groups (for whom Vaccination is available for a given Dose) and Options to select,
    with Key as 'Option' and Value as 'Command'

Example
-------
>>> url_website = "https://www.mooc.e-yantra.org/task-spec/fetch-mock-covidpage"
>>> web_page_data = fetchWebsiteData(url_website)
>>> print(fetchAgeGroup(web_page_data, '1'))
{'1': '18+', '2': '45+'}
>>> print(fetchAgeGroup(web_page_data, '2'))
{'1': '18+', '2': '45+'}
"""

age_group_dict = {}
####


####

return age_group_dict
```

PS-> I am pretty new to programming and learning so please mind the bad code.

PPS->[This sort of thing is what I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drHV8.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, I modifed your code a little bit:

- Example 01 - Not what Questioner wants! [Without Output]
- Example 02 - Customized what Questioner want to have [With Output]
- Example 03 - How I do the work [With Output]

**Example 01:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def fetchWebsiteData(url_website):
    web_page_data = ''
    ####
    req = requests.get(url_website)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
    ####
    ####Changes here
    return soup

def fetchVaccineDoses(web_page_data):
    dose_count = 0
    vaccine_doses_dict = {}
    ####
    doses = web_page_data.find_all('td', class_="dose_num")
    
    ####Changes here too
    for dose in doses:
        vaccine_doses_dict[dose_count] = "Dose " + dose.text
        dose_count = dose_count + 1
        
    ####
    return vaccine_doses_dict

####Changes here too - Complete your empty function with code - 
####I hope it is your output what you want to see.
def fetchAgeGroup(web_page_data, doses):
    age_count = 0
    ####
    ages = web_page_data.find_all('td', class_="age")
    
    for age in ages:
        doses[age_count] = doses[age_count] + " | Age " + age.text
        age_count = age_count + 1
        
    ####
    return doses

url_website = "https://www.mooc.e-yantra.org/task-spec/fetch-mock-covidpage"
web_page_data = fetchWebsiteData(url_website)

VaccineDoses = fetchVaccineDoses(web_page_data)
Ages = fetchAgeGroup(web_page_data, VaccineDoses)

####Ages element 0 can delete because it contains no numbers
####It is only the table header
del Ages[0]

print(Ages)
```

**Example 02:**

So, here the result code of your picture example.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def fetchWebsiteData(url_website):
    web_page_data = ''
    ####
    req = requests.get(url_website)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
    ####
    return soup

def fetchVaccineDoses(web_page_data):
    dose_count = 0
    vaccine_doses_dict = {}
    ####
    doses = web_page_data.find_all('td', class_="dose_num")
    
    for dose in doses:
        if "Dose " + dose.text in vaccine_doses_dict.keys():
            vaccine_doses_dict["Dose " + dose.text] += 1
        else:
            vaccine_doses_dict["Dose " + dose.text] = 1
        dose_count = dose_count + 1  
    ####
    #### Table header remove
    del vaccine_doses_dict["Dose Dose"]
    return vaccine_doses_dict

def fetchAgeGroup(web_page_data, doseNum):
    age_dict = {}
    age_count = 0
    ####
    lines = web_page_data.find_all('tr')
    
    for line in lines:
        if age_count == 0:
            ##Ignore table header
            age_count += 1
            continue
        
        if fetchOnlyNumber(line.find("td", class_="dose_num").text) == doseNum:
            current_age = line.find("td", class_="age").text
            if current_age in age_dict.keys():
                age_dict[current_age] += 1
            else:
                age_dict[current_age] = 1
        
    ####
    return age_dict

def fetchOnlyNumber(inputStr):
    number = 0
    for sChar in inputStr:
        if sChar.isdigit():
            number = (number * 10) + int(sChar)
        else:
            return -1
    return number

def fetchUserInput():
    ### Integer only
    while True:
        print("Choose: ", end="")
        usrInput = fetchOnlyNumber( input() )
        if usrInput > 0:
            return usrInput
        else:
            if usrInput == 0:
                ###Exit
                return 0
            else:
                print("Wrong input! Only numbers are allowed!")


url_website = "https://www.mooc.e-yantra.org/task-spec/fetch-mock-covidpage"
web_page_data = fetchWebsiteData(url_website)
VaccineDoses = fetchVaccineDoses(web_page_data)
indexVacc = 1
print(">>> Select the Dose of Vaccination:")
for VaccineDose, amount in VaccineDoses.items():
    print("{0} :- {1} [Amount: {2}]".format(indexVacc, VaccineDose, amount))
    indexVacc += 1
    
print("0 :- Exit")    
doseNum = fetchUserInput()

if doseNum == 0:
    exit(0)
    
print("<<< Dose Selected: {0}".format(doseNum))
print(">>> Select the Age Group:")
indexAge = 0
Ages = fetchAgeGroup(web_page_data, doseNum)
for age, amount in Ages.items():
    print("{0} :- {1} [Amount: {2}]".format(indexAge, age, amount))
    indexAge += 1
```

**Output of Example 02:**

```
>>> Select the Dose of Vaccination:
1 :- Dose 1 [Amount: 33]
2 :- Dose 2 [Amount: 42]
0 :- Exit
Choose: 2
<<< Dose Selected: 2
>>> Select the Age Group:
0 :- 45+ [Amount: 29]
1 :- 18+ [Amount: 13]
```

**Example 03:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def fetchWebsiteData(url_website):
    web_page_data = ''
    ####
    req = requests.get(url_website)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
    ####
    return soup

def fetchAllPossibleData(web_page_data):
    data_collaction_dict = {}
    doses = {}
    data_index = 0

    ### FOR LOOP BEGINS
    for tr in web_page_data.find_all('tr'):
        if data_index == 0:
            #table header ignore
            data_index += 1
            continue
        hospital_name = tr.find("td", class_="hospital_name").text
        state_name = tr.find("td", class_="state_name").text
        district_name = tr.find("td", class_="district_name").text
        vaccine_name = tr.find("td", class_="vaccine_name").text
        dose_num = tr.find("td", class_="dose_num").text
        age = tr.find("td", class_="age").text

        ### dict = { Key: Value, Key: Value, ... }
        data_collaction_dict[data_index] = {
                "Hospital": hospital_name,
                "State": state_name,
                "District": district_name,
                "Vaccine": vaccine_name,
                "Dose": dose_num,
                "Age": age 
            }

        ### Count "Dose 1" and "Dose 2"
        if dose_num in doses:
            doses[dose_num] += 1
        else:
            doses[dose_num] = 1
            
        data_index += 1
    ### FOR LOOP ENDS

    data_collaction_dict["AmountDose"] = doses
    return data_collaction_dict

def fetchOnlyNumber(inputStr):
    number = 0
    for sChar in inputStr:
        if sChar.isdigit():
            number = (number * 10) + int(sChar)
        else:
            return -1
    return number

def fetchUserInput():
    ### Integer only
    while True:
        print("Choose: ", end="")
        usrInput = fetchOnlyNumber( input() )
        if usrInput > 0:
            return usrInput
        else:
            if usrInput == 0:
                ###Exit
                return 0
            else:
                print("Wrong input! Only numbers are allowed!")


url_website = "https://www.mooc.e-yantra.org/task-spec/fetch-mock-covidpage"
web_page_data = fetchWebsiteData(url_website)
whole_data = fetchAllPossibleData(web_page_data)

dose_index = 1
print(">>> Select the Dose of Vaccination:")
for dose, amount in whole_data["AmountDose"].items():
    print("{0} :- Dose {1} [Amount: {2}]".format(dose_index, dose, amount))
    dose_index += 1
    
print("0 :- Exit")    
doseNum = fetchUserInput()

if doseNum == 0:
    exit(0)
    
print("<<< Dose Selected: {0}".format(doseNum))
print(">>> Select the Age Group:")

for key in whole_data.keys():
    if key == "AmountDose":
        continue

    if int(whole_data[key]["Dose"]) == doseNum:
        print( "Hospital: {0} | Vaccine: {1} | Dose: {2} | Age: {3}".format(
            whole_data[key]["Hospital"],
            whole_data[key]["Vaccine"],
            whole_data[key]["Dose"],
            whole_data[key]["Age"]))
        print('-' * 100)
```

**Output of Example 03:**

```
>>> Select the Dose of Vaccination:
1 :- Dose 1 [Amount: 33]
2 :- Dose 2 [Amount: 42]
0 :- Exit
Choose: 1
<<< Dose Selected: 1
>>> Select the Age Group:
Hospital: Apollo Hospital | Vaccine: Covaxin | Dose: 1 | Age: 45+
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hospital: Springedge Care | Vaccine: Covaxin | Dose: 1 | Age: 18+
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hospital: West Valley Medical Center | Vaccine: Covaxin | Dose: 1 | Age: 45+
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hospital: Zenlife Clinic | Vaccine: Covaxin | Dose: 1 | Age: 18+
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hospital: Family Wellness Center | Vaccine: Covishield | Dose: 1 | Age: 18+
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hospital: Tranquil Valley Hospital Center | Vaccine: Covaxin | Dose: 1 | Age: 45+
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hospital: SevenHills | Vaccine: Covishield | Dose: 1 | Age: 18+
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

.... more output with python script Exapmle 03 - but I think above is enough....

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I see that you have done it right to as what you understood,but what I wanted to do was something like switch case option. It was my bad that you did not understand the question. I am editing my question so please have a look again.

Comment: Okay, I hope it look like as you want it. ^^